# Is there an effort anywhere to collect related answers in an accessible way?

Tags: discussion, answers

It would be really neat to have great answers related to the same type of worldbuilding setting gathered in the same place, sorted and easily accessed.

You know, a collection of the best hand-picked answers related to classic fantasy, or a certain type of planet, a specific environment, or regarding time travel, etc, with answers sorted into different categories. Sort of like a wiki page.

I'm new here, so I wonder if this is perhaps is something that is already happening somewhere?

Comment: The answer by @Secespitus is spot on, but I will be a bit more pedantic. If you go to the top of the WB pages, you can either search terms in the search space in the bar at the top or click on tags. You find questions & their answers grouped together in categories like "space travel: or "planets" or 'xenobiology". It is worthwhile trawling through the questions under the tags. You can do searches by putting in words or phrases related to what you're interested in & see what's there. Either under the full Q&A or under tags. Go for it.

Comment: The closest thing is probably some of the meta posts like https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/creating-a-realistic-world-series where members of the community have collected together related questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No(t in the sense you are asking)

### Why are answers not hand-picked?

"Hand-picking" is very difficult as everyone has different tastes. It's not in the interest of StackExchange to provide a curated list of "moderators monthly picks". Everyone has the right to participate and together we decide as a community what defines "good" and "not so good". The opinions about these categories can vary widely between individuals. I don't know what you would like. I only know what I like.

### Tags

You can always search for the tags and then sort the result by votes. For example to search for great time-travelling answers you can search [[time-travel] is:answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5btime-travel%5d%20is%3aanswer) and then sort by votes.

We have [a lot of different tags](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags) for every occasion. Choose your favourites and browse a bit through them by clicking on one of them and then you can for example sort them by votes to see the communities favourites. We have a few hundred tags, so it's highly likely that you will find something you are interested in.

It's also a good idea to keep an eye out for the tags on your favourite questions. Maybe they use a term you are not familiar with and you can find whole new categories that you like.

### Search tips

We have a Meta Post with some tips about using the search bar that is located in the upper right hand corner. You can find it here: [Search tips wanted please](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/search-tips-wanted-please).

Furthermore there is a great article about searching questions and answers in the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/searching). You can see a shorter versions by clicking on "Advanced Search Tips" in the upper right hand corner after searching something.

Some of my personal favourites to find what you may be looking for:

- use "is:q" to search only for questions -> reduces clutter
- use "is:a" to search only for answers -> if you are searching for great answers this may be your best bet
- use tags with "[stuff]" -> best way to find stuff from a certain category
- add keywords like "multiple dimensions" -> if you are thinking about something more specialized because there are too many questions in your result, such as when only browsing the tag
- remove categories and keywords with a minus when the term is ambiguous -> for example search "is:q mercury -[planets]" to search for questions related to mercury the element and not Mercury the planet
- use "score:x" to only view stuff with at least x upvotes -> if you like sorting by "relevance" it might be a good idea to limit the search to what you consider is a "good" upvote count in your query (**Hint** from [Michael Kjörling](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/is-there-an-effort-anywhere-to-collect-related-answers-in-an-accessible-way/5123?noredirect=1#comment14498_5123): "In searches, `votes:N` is a synonym for `score:N`.")

### Favourites

You can favourite (star) your favourite questions to access the greatest answer on the site for your scenario and in your opinion. Whenever you see a great answer you can just star the corresponding question. You have access to your personal list of favourites in your profile on a dedicated tab and by sorting this list by activity you can always see whenever something happens on such a question.

As you can arbitrarily choose questions you like this list is highly personal and whenever you see activity on this tab it's probably something you are interested in. No need to rely on others.

### Favourite tags

The help center has an interesting post about [How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics). It contains many of the tips I already presented in this post but it also mentions the feature to add favourite tags. Questions that use a tag which you favourited in this way are highlighted on the homepage so that it's easier for you to see them. This way you always up-to-date when it comes to your favourite topics and it's easier to find new interesting posts in these categories. This helps to keep your personal list of starred questions up-to-date, as it's easier for you to see new good posts that you are likely interested in.

On the right side of the homepage you can see a link that says "set tag preferences". By clicking on it you get to your profile settings where you can add favourite tags and ignored tags, which would not be shown on your homepage.

[Michael Kjörling again](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/is-there-an-effort-anywhere-to-collect-related-answers-in-an-accessible-way/5123?noredirect=1#comment14556_5123) had a very nice addition to this: Atom Feeds.

With most RSS-Readers you should be able to read the newest additions to your favourite tags. Example number 1 is [[science-based] [planets] sorted by newest](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=science-based+planets&sort=newest) and example number 2 is [[planets] sorted by newest](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=planets&sort=newest). This is a nice addition if you want to always be up-to-date when it comes to your favourite tags and if you don't want to check WorldBuilding.SE all the time to get information about new and possibly interesting question in the categories you are interested in.

Comment: Related to the section on favorite tags, also don't forget that each tag has its own Atom feed, which can be used with most feed ("RSS") readers. For example, try: [\[science-based\] \[planets\]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=science-based+planets&sort=newest) or [just \[planets\]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=planets&sort=newest).

Answer (score 3):

"best hand-picked" probably won't happen. You may make a meta-post about some series if you feel like it, but hand picking of answers by moderators or staff members is against the idea of community moderation that drives the Stack Exchange network.

If you are interested in some topic, look at its tag, that's what they are for.